# How to map factors and their relative importance in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox, python-2.7, raster-calculator

I want to know how I can calculate a map from a set of factors (in the form of raster layers) and Their relative importance for example:
slope 20%
lithology 10%
.
.
.

Answer (score 2):

This type of geographic analysis can be best best approached imo with [map algebra](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00p600000002000000) (since you are on ArcGIS). I would also look for the [Weighted Overlay GP tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000s1000000) that I think would suit you nicely. It can help overlay analysis layers to solve multi-criteria analysis problems (in your case I guess it is site selection).